# Why Lord Ayyappa Vratam or Mandalam is done only in few months?

Tags: belief, rituals, customs, vrata, ayyappa

Why Lord Ayyappa vratam or mandalam done only during Karthika masa or generally from September - January? I know even temple is generally opened during this period. Is there any reason or shastra behind for going to sabarimala or doing pooja mainly during this time?

Comment: Karthika month seems auspicious. If you look, Shiva took first Bhairava avatar in Karthika month only

Comment: I agree it's auspicious, but that doesn't mean that we should not do mandalam in other months? But in Sabari Mala there won't be or less pooja during other months unlike other temple.

Comment: Makara Sanskranti is important date. See http://sabarimala.tdb.org.in/node/133